# IronPython import two enums with the same name

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, ironpython

why does IronPython allow, to import two enums with the same name from different
namespaces, for example:

```
from System.Windows *
from ESS.MS.Framework.UIG.Mask import *
```

Both import the enum `WindowState` with different members.

It seems, that some time IronPython pick the right enum and some times not.
Very confusing... (IronPython 2.7.4)

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should define an alias:

```
from System.Windows import WindowState as WindowState1
from ESS.MS.Framework.UIG.Mask import WindowState as WindowState2
```

or for the entire module

```
import System.Windows as Module1
import ESS.MS.Framework.UIG.Mask as Module2

//...
Module1.WindowState
Module2.WindowState
```

PS. choose of course better aliases

Comment: I did this to deal with two libraries with similar DLL names Aspose.Cells and Aspose.Words by doing import Aspose.Words as AW // import Aspose.Cells as AC